# How to filter by a boolean value in AppEngine/Java

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to filter my Entities by checking a boolean value:

```
Query stableQuery = new Query(Release.KIND).addFilter("visible", FilterOperator.EQUAL, Boolean.TRUE);
```

This does not return any results though there are entities with visible=true.

I am very clueless and don't even know where to start tracking this down.

Comment: Is visible really a boolean property? Or you just changed that recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Boolean.TRUE, have you tried just using true ?
Would be good if you also shared how are you constructing the entity to see if "visible" property is indeed getting store as a Boolean.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the hint. As this was my first step with AppEngine, I sticked to make it all string, so the visisble property was a string. Of course, it looks the same in the DB view. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
posts = Post.all().filter("published >", False).fetch(100)
```